# set class path in linux and run the jar file making executable

Tags: java, linux, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to run the jar file  on linux created from windows using jdk7 . 
I am using the following command to run the

```
  java -jar jarfile.jar
```

its running the jar and throwing the exception as un recognised class format version. because linux is showing the java version as 1.4.2 while i have extracted the jdk1.7 in the root directory but it is still taking the java version as 1.4.2 . what i have to do to run the jar file created using jdk1.7 . I have extracted the java (jdk1.7) on linux in root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the JDK 1.7 on your path e.g.

```
$ PATH=/jdk17/bin:$PATH
```

Note how you specify not just the path to the 1.7 installation, but the `bin` path `within` that.

Typing

```
$ which java
```

after you've changed the `PATH` will confirm if this has worked.

Comment: its still showing the previous java path as /usr/bin/java means first command not working properly i am writing path=/jdk1.7.0_11/bin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure jdk1.7 in front of jdk1.4.2 in system variable PATH. Do you have installed oracle in your Linux OS? I have encountered the same question in windows OS because I have installed oracle. If some software just like oracle is installed, maybe it will insert jdk1.4 in front of all other software paths in system variable PATH.

Comment: i have not installed oracle on linux and i also have removed the jdk1.4 from linux now not able to set the path for new jdk copied to root